# Apply robustscale from training data to any data set in R

Tags: r, r-caret, normalize

I want to apply the robustscale function from the training data to any data set with the same variables, but it seems that the quantable package does not provide such option like the caret one.

For instance in the caret package you employ the preProcess function and then predict

```
library(caret)
data(BloodBrain)
preProc <- preProcess(bbbDescr[1:100,-3], method=c("scale"))
training <- predict(preProc, bbbDescr[1:100,-3])
test <- predict(preProc, bbbDescr[101:208,-3])
```

And with the quantable package it seems there is no way to apply the scaled data to a new one.

```
library(quantable)
tmp <- matrix(rep((1:100),times = 4) + rnorm(100*4,0,3),ncol=4)
data1 <- robustscale(tmp, dim = 2, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, preserveScale = TRUE)
df<-as.data.frame(data1$data)
```

I wonder, if it is way to apply the robustscale to any other data set, based on a trained one.

Thank you